# How to change the property of td by js?

Tags: javascript, html

Let Table structure is like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>AA</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="a" id="id_a" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="b" id="id_b" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c" id="id_c" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here I need to change the color of text field of `id="id_a"` if xyz is typed in text field `id="id_a"`

Any one can suggest me js script to do so.
But plz don't down-vote. bt may ask what u donot understand about question.

Comment: We all know down-vote is so easy then answering the question. So plz dnt show how u are capable of answering

Comment: People downvote you because this isn't a code writting service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm preparing your answer.. :) plz wait

Comment: It would be nice (and mandatory anyway) to provide some code instead of writing "plz don't down-vote". It would've been even okay a piece of two lines of javascript titled "This is what I've tried but it didn't work" so that people would've believed that you've tried to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Down-vote is surly not the answer nor way to say abt question. But it is so easy to down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Bind an event handler for the input field

```js
document.getElementById('id_a') // get the input field
  .addEventListener('input', function() { //bind event handler
    this.style.color = this.value.trim() == 'xyz' ? 'red' : 'black'; // based on the input value update the color
  })
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>CC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="a" id="id_a" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="b" id="id_b" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="c" id="id_c" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As comments say, this is not a code writting service. You should try to do it on your own, and post here what you have done. Not only the problem.

**The explanation**
You will need a bit of Js for achieving your goal.

First of all, you need to select the element you want to add functionality, in this case `id_a`. This is the reason of the `document.getElementById`.

Next step is adding an `event listener` to the element. This is like saying in a natural language: when the event happends, to the function.
So you are specifying that when the event `keydown` on the element `id_a` happens, run the function passed as callback.

Inside that function, the only thing you have to do is assigning a new class to the element that changes it properties, as `color`, for instance

```js
(function() {
  var e = document.getElementById("id_a");

  e.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    e.className = "red";
  });

})();
```

```css
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>CC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="a" id="id_a" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="b" id="id_b" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="c" id="id_c" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do by selecting all input element by `querySelectorAll` and attach event listener .

*Here I give click event ,you can change what u want*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var field = document.querySelectorAll("input");    
    for(var i =0 ;i<field.length;i++){
        field[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.style.color = "red";
        },false);        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery to solve this

```js
       $('#id_a').on('input',function(e){
        if($('#id_a').val()=='xyz'){
           $("#id_a").css("background-color", "#FFFF00");
        }else{
           $("#id_a").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>AA</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="a" id="id_a" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="b" id="id_b" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c" id="id_c" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```